# Using jQuery to prepend HTML before selected images

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to prepend html before images that have been defined via  a variable named 'products'.

In context - The idea is to add special offer text to product images if they have been defined as sale items (the products listed in the 'products' variable).

I'm almost there but my offer text is being prepended multiple times instead of once for each. I'm assuming that it's my use of the each statement but I'm not sure exactly where it's falling over:

HTML:

```
<ul class="product-list">
  <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Jdtk2XH.png"></li><!-- Targetted -->
  <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/rFEw1ZQ.png"></li><!-- Targetted -->
  <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OZq9PFh.png"></li><!-- Targetted -->
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/EAT4hW8.png"></li><!-- Not targetted -->
  <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8GSRqEg.png"></li><!-- Targetted -->
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    /*Products we're targetting*/
    var products = ["Jdtk2XH", "rFEw1ZQ", "OZq9PFh", "8GSRqEg"];

  $.each( products, function( key, value ) {
    /*For each product found add class*/
        $('ul.product-list li img[src*="' + value + '"]').addClass('special_offer_image');      
        /*On each product with class add something*/
        $( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertBefore( "img.special_offer_image" );

    });
});
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/9ucqdg2e/9/

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem area is `$( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertBefore( "img.special_offer_image" );` it will create a new `P` and will be inserted before every selector.

You need get the reference of `img` and then perform insertion using it.

```
$.each(products, function(key, value) {
    //Get the reference of the img element 
    var img = $('ul.product-list li img[src*="' + value + '"]');
    //Add Class
    img.addClass('special_offer_image');
    //Insert
    $("<p>Test</p>").insertBefore(img);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/9ucqdg2e/12/)

---

Or, Use

```
$.each(products, function(key, value) {
    $('ul.product-list li img[src*="' + value + '"]').addClass('special_offer_image');        

});

//Move outside each()
$("<p>Test</p>").insertBefore('img.special_offer_image');
```